# Trying to construct a polygon from an .uda file

Tags: matlab

I have a .uda file structured like this:

```
1   3
2   4
5   6
```

I tried this

```
pathpoly = 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\polygon\';

polyName = fullfile(pathpoly,'name.uda');

filePoly = importdata(polyName);
```

But it comes out as a 1x1 struct with
filePoly.data as the y axis and
filePoly.textdata as the x axis.

Comment: Can you show exactly what the struct contain? What is `filePoly.data` and `filePoly.textdata`? My guess is that `filePoly.data` contains the values you want.

Comment: Read [the docs on `importdata()`](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html#btk7vi1-1-A). `filePoly.data` will contain your numerical data, `filePoly.textdata` the header data. In other words: `filePoly.data` will contain your 3-by-2 matrix. If this is not the case, please [edit] the question with a [mcve]. Saving that matrix as .uda (or whatever file) and running this code will not return a `.textdata` at all, given you haven't provided a header.

Comment: filePoly.data is the first column of numbers, and textdata is the second column

Comment: If `filePoly.data = [1;2;5]` and `filePoly.textdata = [3;4;6]`, then you can simply concatenate it like this: `[filePoly.data, filePoly.textdata]`.